# logout problems in meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router, logout

I am using the following path to logout in iron-router

```
Router.route('/logout',{
    name: 'logout',
    onBeforeAction: function(){

        Meteor.logout(function(err){
            console.log('logging out' + Meteor.userId());
            Router.go('/');
        });
    }
 });
```

which is used in many places in my app when it is triggered by:

```
Template._loginButtonsLoggedInDropdown.events({

    'click #login-buttons-logout': function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        Router.go('/logout');
    }
});
```

It works fine everywhere but it fails to logout from one template;actually is logs out but after 20secs or so; this specific template has 3 reactive template's vars and 2 subscriptions defined in .onCreated function.
I am looking for any hints why it is so slow and if i should close the template or subscriptions in other way? or any other reason why it logs out so slowly..

version without routers works the same (meaning logout still takes 20sec)

```
'click #login-buttons-logout': function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Meteor.logout(function(err){
        console.log('logging out' + Meteor.userId());
        Router.go('/');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was my subscription although I do not fully understand why.

My code was:

```
Template.observedQuestions.onCreated(function(){
    var self = this;
    self.autorun(function(comp){
        self.subscribe('observedQuestionsFeed');
    });
});
```

which i then changed to:

```
Template.observedQuestions.onCreated(function(){
    computation = Tracker.autorun(function(thisComp){
        status = Session.get('loggingOut');
        console.log('tracker started ' + status);
        mySubscription = self.subscribe('observedQuestionsFeed');
        if (status){
            thisComp.stop();
        }
    });

});
```

where I do stop the computation manually and it works.

thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use a route for the logout. Just change your event handler as follows:

```
Template._loginButtonsLoggedInDropdown.events({
    'click #login-buttons-logout': function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        Meteor.logout(function() {
          Router.go('/');
        }
    }
});
```

And get rid of the route 'logout'.

Comment: I did it before; just wanted to test it in other way; effect is exactly the same meaning it takes 20 secs to log out from this one template while there is not problem logging out from the others..